# How can I prove this sequence $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(b_n^2+1)$ is contractive

Tags: real-analysis

> A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is contractive if there exists $0<r<1$ such that $$\left|a_{n+1}-a_n \right| \le r\left|a_n-a_{n-1} \right|$$ for all $n\ge2$. Let $$b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(b_n^2+1)$$, for $n\ge 1$ and $0<b_1<1$.
> Please prove that $\{b_n\}$ is contractive.

I have thought about this question for a couple of days and I still can't figure out how to do it. I think how $b_n$ defined is meaningful but I can not find some useful inequality to solve this question. I thought arithmetic-geometric mean inequality would help but it fails. Hope someone can give me a hint how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{3}$. Hence

$$|b_{n+1} - b_n| = |f(b_n) - f(b_{n-1})| = |f'(\xi_n)| |b_{n} - b_{n-1}|, $$
where $\xi_n$ lies between $b_{n}$ and $b_{n-1}$.

If $b_1 \in (0,1)$ then it's easy to prove by induction that $b_n \in (0,1)$, $n \ge 1$. Hence $|f'(\xi_n) | \le \sup_{x \in [0,1]} f'(x) = \frac23$.

Thus $$|b_{n+1} - b_n| \le \frac23 |b_{n} - b_{n-1}|$$
and the sequence is contractive with $r = \frac23$.

Comment: I just think of this method

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the difference $b_{n+1}-b_n$, use the reccurence formula and get $r=2/3$.